# Custom classpath on a per application basis in Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, configuration, classpath

I'm trying to have some jar libs outside tomcat and load them only for a specific webapp.

I saw this
/home/ruben/Documents/projetos-tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.35/conf/Catalina/localhost/myapp.xml

but it is not working for me.

I've tried:
- put a myapp.xml in tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost with this content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Context>
    <Loader className="org.apache.catalina.loader.VirtualWebappLoader" virtualClasspath="/home/folder/*.jar" searchVirtualFirst="true"/>
</Context>
```

but no success.

- put context.xml in weapp/myapp/META-INF with same content but no success either.

I'm using tomcat7.

Anyone knows what I'm missing?
Also, I would like to know if this is also possible in tomcat6

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

virtual class path take a full path or

```
<Loader className="org.apache.catalina.loader.VirtualWebappLoader" virtualClasspath="${catalina.base}/home/folder/*.jar" searchVirtualFirst="true"/>
```